# Is there a keyboard shortcut to add an attachment to a Trello card?

Tags: trello, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a hidden keyboard shortcut to add an attachment to a Trello card? I can't find it in the [shortcuts page](https://trello.com/shortcuts).

Comment: I haven't found anything either for regular files, but e.g. screenshots can be pasted with CTRL+V